# Promises function Use in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Can't able to understand the promise function, how to deal with it can anyone explain it through a simple example. Tried it through different sites but got confused in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can understand it with this example:

```
 const request = require("request")

function doSomething(url){
   //return promise from here
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url, function(error, resp, body) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        }
    })
  })
 }

function callDoSomething(){
//initialising a promise
let prom = doSomething(url)
//consume it 
prom.then(function(res) {
 console.log(res)
})
.catch(function(e){
 console.log(e.message)
})
}

callDoSomething()
```

You can also go for `Promise.all` to deal with multiple promise:

```
let prom1 = doSomething(url1)
let prom2 = doSomething(url2)
let prom3 = doSomething(url3)

Promise.all([prom1,prom2,prom3])
.then(res =>{
   //expected output array
   console.log(res)
 })
.catch(e =>{
  console.log(e.message)
 })
```

Comment: Ok, will definetely going to try today

Answer (score 0):

A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers to an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise for the value at some point in the future.

In simple words “A promise is a word taken for some action, the other party who gave the promise might fulfill it or deny it”. In the case of fulfilling, the promise gets resolved, and in another case, it gets rejected.

We can create a promise in JavaScript and use it as an upcoming fact to describe few actions. Promises are kind of design patterns to remove the usage of unintuitive callbacks.

Comment: Refer This Site in details which example -: https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098

Comment: Understand it proper for knowledge as how it works theoretically